# Python - FastAPI - get date as param

Tags: python, mongodb, date, datetime, fastapi

I have a MongoDB database ("signal_API") which contains predictions for next day's stock movements. My collection "predictions_live_API" contains documents which are made of:

1. an id_
2. a date (ex: 2023-05-19T00:00:00.000+00:00)
3. a prediction (ex: 0.6)

I am trying to build an API endpoint with FastAPI, which would return the prepdictions for a given date. My goal is to deliver the date as a param to the endpoint in the following format: YYYY-MM-DD.

I have tried pretty much everything I could think of for the date format, but consistently get errors.

The error I get with the script below is that one:

```
422 Unprocessable Entity
```

```
from fastapi import FastAPI,HTTPException
from pydantic import (
    BaseModel,
    Field,
)  # Pydantic = Data validation and settings management using Python type annotations
from bson import ObjectId
from typing import List
import motor.motor_asyncio  # Motor = Asynchronous Python driver for MongoDB
import datetime

app = FastAPI()
client = motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
db = client.signal_API

class PyObjectId(ObjectId):
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, v):
        if not ObjectId.is_valid(v):
            raise ValueError("Invalid objectid")
        return ObjectId(v)

    @classmethod
    def __modify_schema__(cls, field_schema):
        field_schema.update(type="string")


class Predictions(BaseModel):
    id: PyObjectId = Field(default_factory=PyObjectId, alias="_id")
    date: datetime.date = Field(...)
    symbol: str = Field(...)
    predicted: float = Field(...)

    class Config:
        allow_population_by_field_name = True
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True
        json_encoders = {ObjectId: str}
        schema_extra = {
            "example": {
                "date": "2023-04-28",
                "symbol": "AAPL",
                "predicted": "0.0758",
            }
        }

@app.get(
    "/{date}", response_description="DailyPredictionsByDate", response_model=List[Predictions]
)
async def list_predictions_by_date(date: datetime.datetime):
    predictions = await db["predictions_live_API"].find({"date": date}).to_list(1000)
    return predictions
```

Any help would be more than welcome!

Comment: You're not saying anything about how you're making requests to the endpoint; your parameters to `list_predictions_by_date` work as you expect; making a request to `/2023-01-01T10:00:00Z` gets parsed to a datetime just as you want. The 422 body will have a more details error specification. If you want a _date_, and not a datetime use `datetime.date`, not `datetime.datetime`. `/2023-01-01` works fine in that case.

Comment: Your endpoint expects a `datetime` object, while you are giving it a string. If your desired format is `YYYY-MM-DD`, then you need to treat this as a string, and create a `datetime` object from that string.

Comment: @MatsLindh: Thanks for the heads up. However, if I change datetime.datetime to datetime.date in the function list_predictions_by_date, I get the following error:
`bson.errors.InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: datetime.date(2023, 5, 19), of type: <class 'datetime.date'>`

@JarroVGIT: Thanks a lot, that worked! I added the following to the function list_predictions_by_date: `date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')`